# MongoClient not respecting connectTimeout

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver, database

I am trying to set a connection timeout for the MongoClient (driver version 2.13).

It hangs for 10 seconds then it times out. I need a fast timeout because this code is used in test.

Here is my code:

```
String connectionUri = properties.getProperty("application.mongo.url");
System.out.println("******     "+  connectionUri  + "*******");
MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                                                .connectTimeout(500)
                                                .build();

MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionUri, mongoClientOptions);
```

The [javadoc is describes the connectTimeout](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/) and [this post](http://blog.mongolab.com/2013/10/do-you-want-a-timeout/) describes how to set a timeout.

Has anyone had similar issues and resolved it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the Connection String you are using with the options?

Comment: Also does setting the `socketTimeout` as well, solve the quick fail issue?

http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html#socketTimeout-int-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `MongoClientOptions.builder().serverSelectionTimeout(500).build()` if you want to test server connection. other properties to set in case you want to test them are:

- connectTimeout
- socketTimeout
- heartbeatConnectTimeout
- heartbeatSocketTimeout